# T-SQL A question about inner join table variable

Tags: t-sql

in my stored procedure I have a table variable contains rows ID. The are 2 scenarios - that table variable is empty and not.

```
declare @IDTable as table
(
  number NUMERIC(18,0)
)
```

In the main query, I join that table:

```
inner join @IDTable tab on (tab.number = csr.id)
```

BUT:

as we know how inner join works, I need that my query returns some rows:

> when @IDTable is empty

OR

> return **ONLY** rows that exist in
>   @IDTable

I tried also with LEFT join but it doesn't work. Any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: Show us the `LEFT JOIN` you tried

Comment: the LEFT JOIN looks the sane as the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `@IDTable' is empty then what rows do you return?  Do you just ignore the Join on to the table?

I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do but this might be easier.

```
if (Select Count(*) From @IDTable) == 0
    begin
    -- do a SELECT that doesn't join on to the @IDTable

     end
else
    begin
    -- do a SELECT that joins on to @IDTable
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not optimal, but it works:

```
declare @z table
  (
    id int
  )
  --insert @z values(2)

  select * from  somTable n 
    left join @z z on (z.id = n.id)
  where NOT exists(select 1 from @z) or (z.id is not null)
```

Comment: @Tony cycled table scan of @z and clusterd index scan (or), see execution plan, for small tables it's ok. :)